# Что такое НЕ встраеваемая СУБД? =)

Tags: база-данных, терминология

Прочитал пару статей в википедии, прогуглился, прояндексился, потратил минут 30, ответа так и не могу найти. Ребят, помогите, обьясните что значит НЕ встраеваемая СУБД? И куда она не встраивается? Я имею ввиду: если все они встраиваемые бы были, то зачем тогда это слово говорить? А раз уточняют значит существуют еще и какие то НЕ встиаевыемые? Можно примеры таких баз? И что это вообще означает не встраеваемая?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть приоложение, например, настольное, и вы можете накатить это приложение на голый компьютер и оно само создаст там базу данных, без какого либо доп ПО, то такая БД называется встраиваемая. Например SQLite или SQLCompact. Если для работы с БД вам надо устанавливать СУБД, например SQL Server, Oracle, etc, то такие БД не встраиваемые. Вы не можете пользоваться базой SQL Server без установки самого SQL Server.

Для уточнения, БД - это база данный, по сути файл или набор файлов. СУБД - это система упраления базой данных, то есть ПО, которое позволяет иметь доступ и управлять файлами базы данных. SQLite не имеет СУБД, оно имеет только библиотеку, которую вы можете ку себе добавить в ваше приложение и все дела. SQL Server же не позволяет няпрямую писать в файлы БД, он принимает запросы от клиентов и сам уже их выполняет.

Comment: То есть если я в установщик своей программки запихаю постгресс, и под капотом его тихо установлю, то я как бы ВСТРОЮ постгресс, и он перестанет быть невстраевоемой бы и превратится во встраеваемую?) Или вы имеете ввиду мол "А насколько УДОБНО будет встроить бд", мол некоторые предназначенны для удобного встраивания а некоторые нет? В этом идея?)

Comment: Постгресс ставится как отдельное по, а значит это уже не встраиваемая бд. Как правило, встраиваемые бд представляют собой библиотеки, которые добавляются в приложение.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное если честно) меня этот вопрос лет 10 гложил я просто его проглатывал ахах)